# Why do I still need to do COPY in my Dockerfile if I'm using a Bind Mount?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, containers

So I'm in a developemnt environment and I'm binding my code inside a container using Mount Bind in my docker-compose file:

```
...
volumes:
       - ./my-code:/home/node/app    
       - /home/node/app/node_modules
...
```

But I still need do COPY inside my Dockerfile in order to make this work.

`COPY --chown=node:node . .`

What I don't get is. If I'm binding my code to the container inside docker-compose.yml, why do I still need to copy all my code in the Dockerfile?

Comment: When you bind the code in a volume using docker compose, you care binding it to the container. The moment you do docker-compose down, the container is removed and the code inside of it is lost. When you copy the code in the dockerfile, you are copying it to the image and unless you delete the image, the code will remain inside the image and can run normally. Additionally, when you push to a repository, you push the image, not the container so you want the code to be in the image independent of how it is run.

Comment: @camba1 But why use volumes then? If the code is inside our image, this means it will be inside the container too when it runs. Then why bind it to container?

Comment: @MazharAli, one reason could be if you wanted to development locally (on your host machine) and have file changes there reflected in the running container.