# Substituting the npm links for Docker container (case with Node.js "node:12.4" and "docker-compose" file)

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, lerna

### Project

[image]

There are dependencies provided via Lerna (I suppose, it using the `npm link`) inside `node_modules` (assume `dependency_a` and `dependency_b`). The project building works without Docker, but Docker don't see the links to `dependency_a` and `dependency_b`. With below `docker-compose.yaml`:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  logic:
    image: node:12.4
    command: npm run 'SPA incremental building' && npm run 'Run server'
    volumes:
      - .:/Application
    working_dir: /Application
```

I have error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/packages/dependency_a/bin/dependency_a'.
```

### Logic of the solution

1. From the viewpoint of NPM and Lerna, nothing wrong has done (at least, linking is working without Docker). But this "right" way is "wrong" for Docker.
2. Docker must not break the basic concept of NPM as dependencies linking. It means when we tell to Docker where is `dependency_a`, the **normal 'SPA incremental building' without Docker still must work**. (Image what will be if each tool will decide which rules are right!)
3. Because of **2**, Docker must leave the way to tell **just to him** where is the `dependency_a`. If this way exists, it is the solution.

### Conceptual solution

**For Docker container only** (not local environment) replace npm links inside `node_modules` to such links as Docker can understand. It's important that **Docker must see the changes of these dependencies** because the are being frequently updated.

It could be something like:

```yaml
version: "3"

services:

  logic:
    image: node:12.4
    command: npm run 'SPA incremental building' && npm run 'Run server'
    volumes:
      - .:/Application
      - ../../packages/dependency_a:/Application/node_modules/dependency_a
      - ../../packages/dependency_b:/Application/node_modules/dependency_a
    working_dir: /Application
#    ports:
#      - "3000:3000"
```

But

1. I am not sure what I actually doing.
2. I don't feeling good about intersection of volumes (second and third volumes overrides first).
3. Above settings does not works.

Off course, I telling about **local development mode**, not about production.

### Related article analysis

The similar situation considering in the article [Developing a new Node module in a Docker container without using NPM link](https://properdesign.co.uk/developing-a-new-node-module-in-a-docker-container-without-using-npm-link/). The solution for the case in this article:

```
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/node_modules
 
ENV PATH /usr/src/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
```

and the in `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
volumes:
- .:/usr/src/app
- ../redux-beacon-slack:/usr/src/node_modules/redux-beacon-slack
```

Why this solution does not suite with my case because I am using `node:12.4` image. I suppose, the paths like `usr/src` are actual for images of operation systems, but I don't understand if I need to create the file system (like `bin`, `boot`, `cdrom`, `home`, `root`, etc.) in my `node:12.4` image.

### Inappropriate solutions

#### Use only published npm libraries without npm links

**The well-organized development environment is the basic requirement of modern IT industry**. In relation to locally developing `npm` dependencies:

1. No excess realizes (to `npm`).
2. If we changed something in locally developing dependency, the changes must immediately reflect on application (what npm link providing). E. g. if we added `console.log()` somewhere in `dependency_a`, we instantly see this output in our application.

#### Changing of project structure

IMHO good software must adapt to custom project structure, not force own project structure.

Comment: Could you show your `Dockerfile`? Do you have one?

Comment: @a1300, I have no, and don't want to have without necessity (by other word each new file must be added with rational reason). AFAIK we can tell to Docker what we want via `docker-compose.yaml`, but I will solution with `Dockerfile` if it really required.

Comment: You need a `Dockerfile`!. `docker-compose` can't start a container if you have no `Dockerfile`. Here is a good article as a base for your `Dockerfile` [react-in-docker-with-nginx](https://medium.com/@tiangolo/react-in-docker-with-nginx-built-with-multi-stage-docker-builds-including-testing-8cc49d6ec305)

Comment: @a1300, Here is the [example](https://github.com/ishidait/docker-nodejs/tree/blog-3) without Dockerfile. The [related article](https://ishida-it.com/blog/post/2019-11-23-docker-nodejs-mysql/) is not English, but you can view code and use browser automatic translation.

Comment: @TakesiTokugawaYD At what poin are you copying your local files to the Docker container ?  for example: to be able to run `npm install` in your docker container you should first copy the package.json file. It would be easier with a Docker file.

Comment: @MiguelGiménez, thank you for the comment. "At what point are you copying your local files to the Docker container ?" - I think no, because AFAIK creating the volume does not mean to copying of something (if I wrong please explain). What I am going to do is mount all my project structure (in the picture) as volume to Docker container.

Comment: @TakesiTokugawaYD  you are actually binding your local directory to the volume (which means copying) when you add the colon `:` in the volumes part of the docker-compose file, but I believe still you need to copy look at this answer  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62734082/why-do-i-still-need-to-do-copy-in-my-dockerfile-if-im-using-a-bind-mount

Comment: @MiguelGiménez, looks like I did not understand the "volumes" concept... I had not target to copy the files. Just "copy" word cause concern: will Docker container update in real time when the files from which we make the copy updated? I suppose NO. So maybe I make wrong decision when selected the volumes for my targets.